# Own Hibernate DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener is not getting fired when using .save() or .update() instead of .saveOrUpdate()

Tags: hibernate

im trying to build a spring (3.1) & hibernate (3.6.10) web application and having a problem with the hibernate events.
I implemented my own DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener for updating/creating a dateCreated and lastUpdated date which is called on every .saveOrUpdate() event. So far so good.

Shouldn't this listener be called also on .save() or .update() events?
Or am i missing something here?

Listener:

```
public class SaveOrUpdateDateListener extends DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SaveOrUpdateDateListener.class);


    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
        log.debug("Entered onSaveOrUpdate()");

        if (event.getObject() instanceof BaseDomain) {
            BaseDomain record = (BaseDomain) event.getObject();

            record.setDateUpdated(new Date());

            if (record.getDateCreated() == null) {
                record.setDateCreated(new Date());
            }
        }

        super.onSaveOrUpdate(event);
    }
}
```

Hibernate config (partially):

```
<sesssion-factory>

<event type="save-update">
            <listener class="net.test.listener.hibernate.SaveOrUpdateDateListener"/>
            <listener class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener"/>
        </event>    
</session-factory>
```

example dao methods (**doesn't work**):

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Override
public void add(Registration registration) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(registration);
}

@Override
public void update(Registration registration) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(registration);
}
```

example dao methods (**works**):

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Override
public void add(Registration registration) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(registration);
}

@Override
public void update(Registration registration) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(registration);
}
```

**Edit**

After i dedcided not to use saveOrUpdate in general i hopefully solved my problem with using a base class like the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseDomain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    protected Timestamp dateCreated;

    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    protected Timestamp dateUpdated;


    protected BaseDomain() {
        this.dateCreated = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateUpdated() {
        return dateUpdated;
    }
}
```

As the current_timestamp can be used only once per table (mysql restriction) i tried to build the dateCreated via constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save-update events occurs only as a consequence of calling saveOrUpdate. Save-update is not some kind of combinations of save, update. and saveOrUpdate.

In [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-events) this is spelled following way:

> 14.2. Event system
>   ...
>   All the methods of the Session interface correlate to an event.
>   ...
>   When a request is made of one of these methods, the Hibernate Session
>   generates an appropriate event and passes it to the configured event
>   listeners for that type.